What is the use of creating a copy of the input in a recursive call?
This is a code to generate all the substrings in of a given vector
class Solution {
public:
    void sub(vector<int> &ip, vector<int> &op, vector<vector<int>> &ans) {
    if (ip.size() == 0) {
        ans.push_back(op);
        return;
    }

    // Create a copy of ip to avoid modifying the original vector
    vector<int> ip_copy(ip);

    vector<int> op_one = op;
    vector<int> op_two = op;
    op_two.push_back(ip_copy[0]);
    ip_copy.erase(ip_copy.begin());

    sub(ip_copy, op_one, ans);
    sub(ip_copy, op_two, ans);
    return;
}

vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int> &nums) {
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    vector<int> op;
    sub(nums, op, ans);
    return ans;
}

};
my questions is, why must I create a copy of the ip? When the copy is passed into the next recursive call, why can't I use the original input only? (apart from ofcourse, preserving info)
This code below, does not give the substring that have more than one integer in them..
class Solution {
public:
void sub(vector<int> &ip, vector<int> &op, vector<vector<int>> &ans) {
    if(ip.size() == 0) {
        ans.push_back(op);
        return;
    }
    vector<int> op_one = op;
    vector<int> op_two = op;
    op_two.push_back(ip[0]);
    ip.erase(ip.begin());
    sub(ip, op_one, ans);
    sub(ip, op_two, ans);
    return;
}
vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    vector<int> op;
    sub(nums, op, ans);
    return ans;
}

};

You are modifying the vector, obviously modifying a copy is different than modifying a reference. Maybe you should go step by step with both versions of your function and note down all values of all variables to understand what is happening in each case?

When I am putting in the same copy into the recursive function after changing it up, why not use the same vector, when preserving info is not a priority

You are putting the same copy into a reference parameter twice. Without the copy, each of those calls modifies the ip. The much simpler thing would be to take ip (and op) by value.

when preserving info is not a priority Is it not? You said yourself that if you modify the original vector instead of copy, your code doesn't work as you expect. Sounds like a good reason to prioritise preserving info.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?


When the copy is passed into the next recursive call, why can't I use the original input only?

Because the original ip is a reference. If you don't copy it, the first recursive call modifies it before the second call.
If you do copy it then each sibling call has the same state.
However I find it very suspicious to have a function that accepts by reference and copies in the body. Much simpler is to just take by value.
class Solution {
public:
vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int> ip, vector<int> op = {}) {
    if(ip.size() == 0) {
        return { op };
    }
    int value = ip[0];
    ip.erase(ip.begin());
    vector<vector<int>> ans_one = sub(ip, op);
    op.push_back(value);
    vector<vector<int>> ans_two = sub(ip, op);
    ans_one.insert(ans_one.end(), ans_two.begin(), ans_two.end());
    return ans_one;
}

